# AngularJS test if $scope method has been called

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a method called `$scope.openGroupInbox()` which does `$scope.init()` and other stuff.
I want to test if `$scope.init()` has been called.
So I'm doing this:

```
it('call init', function () {
    $scope.openGroupInbox(3);
    expect($scope.init(3)).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you call the `.toHaveBeenCalled()` function in your test. You need to register a spy that will keep track of calls made to the `$scope.init()` function.

You could do this in your `beforeEach` like below.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn($scope, 'init');
});
```

Then when your test runs you should correctly get informed whether or not the `$scope.init()` function has been successfully called.

You will also need to change the your `expect` to either:

```
expect($scope.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

or

```
expect($scope.init).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
```

I hope this helps.